# Как реализовать произношение слов в моем мобильном приложении

Tags: алгоритм

Я делаю приложение для изучения английских слов.
В том числе там будет функция послушать как это слово произносится.
Теперь я думаю как это реализовать.
Идея, которая сразу пришла в голову: при добавлении прогонять слово через синтезатор речи, а аудиозапись, которая получилась, хранить на сервере. Ну и каждый раз когда произношение этого слова пытаются прослушать, отправлять этот аудиофайл.
Но мне почему-то кажется, что есть какой-то вариант получше.
Может быть, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей и знает как реализовать это более красиво

Comment: То есть синтезатор будет английски корректно произносить слова? С ударениями и паузами где надо?

Comment: проверять можно
там если что есть же функция поставить ударение вручную